# SimpleDateFormat returning NULL Date with JDK7 , but working fine with JDK6

Tags: java-7

I have this sample java code where I am trying to parse a String into Date , based on the patter set on SimpleDateFormat. When I run this code in JDK6 , its working fine. But in JDK7, a NULL been return on parse call. Any idea what has been changed with JDK7 . Is this a known issue or any workaround ?

```
  SimpleDateFormat _theSimpleDateFormatHelper =  new SimpleDateFormat();
  _theSimpleDateFormatHelper.setLenient(false);
  _theSimpleDateFormatHelper.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

  ParsePosition parsePos = new ParsePosition(0);
  Object formattedObj = _theSimpleDateFormatHelper.parse("1989-09-21 00:00:00", parsePos);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code works fine:

```
SimpleDateFormat _theSimpleDateFormatHelper =  new SimpleDateFormat();
//_theSimpleDateFormatHelper.setLenient(false); <-- In lenient mode, the parsing succeeds
_theSimpleDateFormatHelper.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

ParsePosition parsePos = new ParsePosition(0);
Object formattedObj = _theSimpleDateFormatHelper.parse("1989-09-21 00:00:00", parsePos);
```

The reason it doesn't work is because the format is incorrect in strict mode. From this page http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html, you can see that the `h` range is 1-12.

If you use `H` instead, the range is 0-23 and this will work as well:

```
SimpleDateFormat _theSimpleDateFormatHelper =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
_theSimpleDateFormatHelper.setLenient(false);
Object formattedObj = _theSimpleDateFormatHelper.parse("1989-09-21 00:00:00");
```